# How to find ASCII value of a character in wtx

Tags: wtx

In a string, I want to replace all the characters between ASCII value of 0-32 and 127-255 to spaces. I have been breaking my head for 4 days and but not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for replacing ranges, but you can use the `SUBSTITUTE` function to replace each individual character.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(string,
SYMBOL(0), " ",
SYMBOL(1), " ",
// etc.
SYMBOL(254), " ",
SYMBOL(255), " ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Bo.